# WPF: Not able to set color in resource through binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

We have our different icons in form of xaml resources in the application something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<DrawingBrush x:Key="My_Icon">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="Gray"> <!--I want to set this Brush here using binding-->
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="45" RadiusY="20" />
                    <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="45" />
                </GeometryGroup>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

And we use these resources in another xaml file (load this resource in code behind, refer to the code below)

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var resource = Application.Current.FindResource("My_Icon");
        this.MyBrush = resource as DrawingBrush;

        NewBrush = Brushes.Blue;

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private DrawingBrush _myBrush;

    public DrawingBrush MyBrush
    {
        get { return _myBrush; }
        set { _myBrush = value; }
    }

    private Brush _newBrush;

    public Brush NewBrush
    {
        get { return _newBrush; }
        set { _newBrush = value; }
    }
}
```

The issue is, I am not able to set the icon color (in resource code, the first code snippet) using the binding, with property which is in ViewModel (MyBrush property in this case in Window2 code behind)

I tried with following code in resource file:

```
<GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Rectangle}, Path=NewBrush}">
```

But this isn't working. What I might be missing here.

Comment: Did you include the resource dictionary?

Comment: Yes. That I did. It's a working sample with Gray color which I have set. All I want to do is, set this color with a binding.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. Judging by your last code snippet you're trying to bind `GeomertyDrawing.Brush` property to `Window2.MyBrush` property, which holds the `<DrawingBrush x:Key="My_Icon">"`, which in turn is the parent of the `GeometryDrawing` - this leads to a circular dependency and will most definitely lead to an exception...

Comment: I just edited the question. Apologies for mistake

Comment: Can you add a sample project?

Comment: Ok, now it makes more sense. Although you removed the `Window2` XAML code, but assuming that `<DrawingBrush x:Key="My_Icon">` is referenced somewhere in it the problem should be resolved by replacing `AncestorType=Rectangle` with `AncestorType=local:Window2` (note that `Rectangle` type does not contain a property named `NewBrush`). Also, remember to include appropriate namespace declaration for `local` prefix.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it, but I still see the following error:

Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='PracticeWPFApp.Window2', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=NewBrush; DataItem=null; target element is 'GeometryDrawing' (HashCode=12289634); target property is 'Brush' (type 'Brush')

Comment: Well, I was afraid it would turn out like this. Let me get back to you in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've came up with two ways to resolve your problem.

**Solution I** (better in my opinion)

Give up your code-behind approach and import your resource dictionary directly into your window resources and use `StaticResourceExtension` to reference the resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="TheNameOfYourDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
...
<Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource My_Icon}"/>
```

When you do that and use `AncestorType=local:Window2` your binding should work (although in current shape subsequent changes to `NewBrush` property won't be reflected in the drawing - refer to the list at the end of this answer). Note that it is necessary to use `{StaticResource My_Icon}` instead of `{Binding MyBrush}`.

**Solution II**

Set the binding in your code-behind:

```
var resource = Application.Current.FindResource("My_Icon");
this.MyBrush = resource as DrawingBrush;

NewBrush = Brushes.Blue;

BindingOperations.SetBinding(MyBrush.Drawing, GeometryDrawing.BrushProperty,
    new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("NewBrush"), Source = this });
```

Note that in order for this (or the first solution) to work one of these conditions should be met:

1. `NewBrush` is set before the binding is set (before `DataContext` is set in case of the first solution)
2. `Window2` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `PropertyChanged` event is raised after `NewBrush` is set
3. `NewBrush` is a dependency property

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would go for the second approach, because we load different resource at run time for different conditions (Different icons for different entity type). 

So I might be referring to a separate resource each time. Do you think I can still do that with Solution I, which you have given.

Also, should I have null check for the Drawing in the resource, may be for some resources I don't have Drawing there. And if yes, how to put that null check.

Comment: There is a small issue I am facing:   If I taking off the Brush binding code in resource, I get error. 


i. e. if i change <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:Window2}, Path=NewBrush}"> to

<GeometryDrawing> I get this error:  "Cannot set a property on object 'System.Windows.Media.GeometryDrawing' because it is in a read-only state."

Comment: @DotnetRocks Regarding your first comment - if you mean dynamically referencing different resources based on some condition(s) then it can be done in XAML - see [Styling triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#styling_triggers). As for the second problem, it occurs because apparently unless you set a binding on the `GeometryDrawing` it's returned, as mentioned, in a "read-only" state. A workaround would be to use a modifiable copy of the `DrawingBrush` obtained by `Clone()` method, i.e. `MyBrush = ((DrawingBrush)resource).Clone();`