# Why I can change a resource properties when it defined at Windows.Resources but not from Application.Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

**Problem:**

I notice if I define the same resource in my `Windows.Resources` I can do some changes to its properties when I bind to them in `TwoWay` mode, but no luck if I define it in `Application.Resources`. I know something about Static/Dynamic Resources and I thought both places should be Static!

**Question:**

Why can we make some changes in a resource when we defined it at `Windows.Resources` level? Is it initialized as a `DynamicResource` when it is defined in `Windows.Resources`? Or are there other reasons!?

Side Question: Is there a way to make it work when we define it in `Application.Resources`?

**Code to Examine**

Define a resource at Windows-Level and bind to it and change its property without any problem:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="GreenYellow"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Background="{StaticResource MyBrush}" Content="Button 1" Margin="10"/>
        <Button Background="{StaticResource MyBrush}" Content="Button 2" Margin="10"/>
        <Slider Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyBrush}, Path=Opacity, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Maximum="1" TickFrequency="0.01"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

But If I move the resource definition into `Application.Resources` like this:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="GreenYellow"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I get this exception in my Output window:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 8 : Cannot save value from target back to source. BindingExpression:Path=Opacity; DataItem='SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=37320431); target element is 'Slider' (Name=''); target property is 'Value' (type 'Double') InvalidOperationException:'System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot set a property on object '#FFADFF2F' because it is in a read-only state.
```

I think it is the correct response, since the above resource is defined as static. I tried this trick to solve above problem:

```
<Slider DataContext="{DynamicResource MyBrush}" Value="{Binding Path=Opacity, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Maximum="1" TickFrequency="0.01"/>
```

No luck! Still my main question is why is it acting differently when we are using resources at `Windows.Resources`!?

**Searches to find answer until now**

I read these, but no answer that I'm looking for:

[WPF: cannot change style SolidColorBrush via code behind because read-only state [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45048448)

[Changing SolidColorBrush#Color in resource dictionary failed: Property is readonly [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38152931)

[Binding SolidColorBrush to ControlTemplate Background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34895192)

[WPF: Not able to set color in resource through binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30138110)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`SolidColorBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush?view=net-5.0) is a type derived from [`Freezable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.freezable?view=net-5.0), see its inheritance chain.

> Object > DispatcherObject > DependencyObject > **Freezable** > Animatable > Brush > SolidColorBrush

A [`Freezable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.freezable?view=net-5.0) is a special type that can be frozen at runtime, which makes it unmodifiable.

> Defines an object that has a modifiable state and a read-only (frozen) state. Classes that derive from Freezable provide detailed change notification, can be made immutable, and can clone themselves.

The `InvalidOperationException` is an indicator that the `SolidColorBrush` was already frozen.

> To make a Freezable unmodifiable, you call its [`Freeze`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.freezable.freeze?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Freezable_Freeze) method. When you freeze an object that contains freezable objects, those objects are frozen as well. [...]
> Once you call a freezable's Freeze method, it can no longer be modified. Attempting to modify a frozen object causes an `InvalidOperationException` to be thrown.

Accoriding to this [MSDN forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b3ca4b1e-e269-4cb4-872d-ca4c90ce8064/applicationresources-are-automatically-frozen?forum=wpf), application resources are always frozen automatically.

> -> Are Resources which are defined in the Application.Resources always frozen.
>
> This is a by design side effect.

In fact, looking at the reference source for `ResourceDictionary` you can see that there is a [`SealValue` method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/ResourceDictionary.cs,2302) that is called if resources are added via the `Add` method or an indexer. The comment says it all.

> This method
>
> 1. Sets the InheritanceContext of the value to the dictionary's principal owner
> 2. **Seals the freezable/style/template that is to be placed in an App/Theme/Style/Template ResourceDictionary**

Consequently, your `SolidColorBrush` and any other freezable object is frozen automatically in the application resource dictionary. This is by design, I guess it could be due to performance reasons.

> A Freezable provides a Changed event to notify observers of any modifications to the object. Freezing a Freezable can improve its performance, because it no longer needs to spend resources on change notifications. A frozen Freezable can also be shared across threads, while an unfrozen Freezable cannot.

As a side note on the reference source: All types that implement `ISealable` are sealed there. In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.freezable?view=net-5.0), there is no notion of `Freezable` implementing `ISealable`, but according to its [reference source](http://A%20Freezable%20provides%20a%20Changed%20event%20to%20notify%20observers%20of%20any%20modifications%20to%20the%20object.%20Freezing%20a%20Freezable%20can%20improve%20its%20performance,%20because%20it%20no%20longer%20needs%20to%20spend%20resources%20on%20change%20notifications.%20A%20frozen%20Freezable%20can%20also%20be%20shared%20across%20threads,%20while%20an%20unfrozen%20Freezable%20cannot.) it does and it explicitly implements the [`Seal`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Base/System/Windows/Freezable.cs,774) method by simply calling `Freeze`.

---

Regarding your understanding of static and dynamic resources, a resource is neither defined static nor dynamic, they are *just resources*. [`StaticResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/staticresource-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-5.0) and [`DynamicResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dynamicresource-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-5.0) are just markup extensions that define how you reference a resource, which implies its *lookup behavior*.

- [Static and dynamic resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/xaml-resources-define?view=netdesktop-5.0#static-and-dynamic-resources)
- [Static resource lookup behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/xaml-resources-define?view=netdesktop-5.0#static-resource-lookup-behavior)
- [Dynamic resource lookup behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/xaml-resources-define?view=netdesktop-5.0#dynamic-resource-lookup-behavior)

Is there a way to make your desired behavior work with the application resource dictionary? I do not think so, since the code explicitly freezes resources even in merged resource dictionaries, so defining a separate resource dictionary will not work, [`PresentationOptions:Freeze="False"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/presentationoptions-freeze-attribute?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) does not work either. Consequently, defining the resource in a different scope seems to be the only option.